# Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array - pdo query

Tags: php, pdo

I've taken a look at similar articles on stack, but I can't seem to work out this issue.

I'm getting a "PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array."

This is the query function;

```
function query($query, $bindings, $conn)
{
   $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
   $stmt->execute($bindings);

   return $stmt;
}
```

This is the query I run;

```
$testimonials = query ('SELECT * FROM testimonials ORDER BY id = :id DESC LIMIT 1', 
                        array('id' => ['id']), $conn)[0];
```

Then posting the data;

```
<?= $testimonials['testimonial']; ?>
```

Comment: print `$testimonials` it is an object not an array

Comment: `['id'] =/= 'id'`. `['id']` is the same as `array('id')`.

Comment: why are you trying to access an `[0]` index zero on a PDO statement? it doesn't make sense. you need to fetch values from that before getting any values from your select statement

Comment: Try splitting your code up to make it more manageable - even if it worked, immediately accessing index [0] on a function return is hard to read and can confuse what you're doing. Try using variable names to describe _what_ you're doing in each line. In this case as the first commenter said, your issue is that the `return $stmt` line is not returning an array, it's a PDO object.

Comment: Could someone please post an answer, as I have 3 comments thanks.